# C++ turning string into char and making it unable to compare to another string

Tags: c++

```
void split_to_array(string sentence, string splitter)
{
    int index = 0;
    int last_index = sentence.find(splitter);

    int array_amount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < sentence.size(); i++) {
        cout << sentence[i] << endl;
        if (sentence[i] == splitter) array_amount++;
    }
}

int main()
{

    split_to_array("fdsfds fdsfds vcxvcx fdsafdsa", " ");

}
```

I am trying to get the length of the array by finding the splitter argument in the string, However when I try to compare the index of the string with the splitter I get an error that I cannot compare a char with a string which is the first issue I have. When I try to turn it  into a string by using std::to_string I get a number back instead of the actual string.

Comment: Make it `void split_to_array(string sentence, char splitter)` and call it as: `split_to_array("fdsfds fdsfds vcxvcx fdsafdsa", ' ');`

Comment: but what if I change the ' ' to a string then it wouldn't work with char right.

Comment: Right, so don't :)

Comment: ye but I want to make it dynamic tho, would I have to write a different function or do I check if the string is longer then 1 and make it a char within the function?

Comment: You should clarify your requirements in the question.  Please don't make them up in the comments.

Comment: yes, sorry. I've got the answer to my question thanks.

Comment: `absl::StrSplit()`

Comment: If you always want to split on exactly 1 character, change `splitter` to type `char` as Paul previously suggested.  If you sometimes want to split on a multi-character string, you'll instead need to change the comparison to `if (sentence.substr(i, splitter.size()) == splitter) { ... }`.  This extracts a substring from `sentence` rather than a single character, which is what `sentence[i]` does.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this

```
if(sentence[i] == splitter)
```

`sentence[i]` is a single character. splitter is a string.

I would fix it by passing a char argement for splitter. ie

```
void split_to_array(string sentence, char splitter)
```

and

```
 split_to_array("fdsfds fdsfds vcxvcx fdsafdsa", ' ');
```

if you want to keep the same function signatures for some reasons then do

```
 if(sentence[i] == splitter[0])
```

ie compare against the first (and only) characer in splitter. This is however a very odd thing to do.

Answer (score -1):

```
void split_to_array(string sentence, char splitter)
{
    int index = 0;
    int last_index = sentence.find(splitter);

    int array_amount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < sentence.size(); i++) {
        cout << sentence[i] << endl;
        if (sentence[i] == splitter) array_amount++;
    }
}

int main()
{

    split_to_array("fdsfds fdsfds vcxvcx fdsafdsa", ' ');

}
```

Maybe do it like this. Eventually you send "splitter" parameter as a char so it is easier to compare. You need to use apostrophe (') for a char when calling a function.